# Explanation of gensub() in gawk

Tags: awk

I had a requirement where i had to remove the `,` in the second last line in a file as below

```
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/2egt.dbf',
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/sddd.dbf',
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/dfcf.dbf',
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/rttemp.dbf',
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/oxiule.dbf',
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/sdafrtt.dbf',
 CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8
 ;
```

I achieved it using a gawk command as below from this forum:

`-bash-3.2$ gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '{print gensub(/,([^,]+)$/, "\\1", "")}' tstop1`

***[EDIT]:** The original question display `"\1"` caused by incorrect format but it actually means `"\\1"`*

Output obtained as the required output:

```
  '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/2egt.dbf',
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/sddd.dbf',
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/dfcf.dbf',
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/rttemp.dbf',
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/oxiule.dbf',
   '/tols/tope/triy8/ffgy/890/oki4/sdafrtt.dbf'
 CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8
 ;
```

But i am not understanding the command, especially this part `gensub(/,([^,]+)$/, "\\1", "")` ...
I got the below from manual of `gensub`:

> `gensub(r, s, h [, t])`   Search  the target string `t` for matches of
> the regular expression `r`.  If `h` is a string beginning with `g` or
> `G`, then replace all matches of `r` with `s`.  Otherwise, `h` is a
> number  indicating  which match  of  `r` to replace.  If `t` is not
> supplied, `$0` is used instead.  Within the replacement texts, the
> sequence `\n`, where `n` is a digit from 1 to 9, may be used to
> indicate just the  text  that matched  the  `n`’th  parenthesized
> subexpression.  The sequence `\0` represents the entire matched text,
> as does the character `&`.  Unlike `sub()` and `gsub()`, the modified
> string is returned as  the result of the function, and the original
> target string is not changed.

But in my case, how `gensub` gets the second last line and how it substitutes the `,` with null ...?
Can someone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not getting the 2nd-last line, it's removing the last `,` in the file no matter which line that's on.

1. `-v RS='\0'` means "read the whole file in as a single string" (BUG #1)
2. `-v ORS=` means "don't **add** a newline at the end of the output"
3. `/,([^,]+)$/` means "match a comma followed by non-commas til the end of the string"
4. `"\1"` means "replace whatever matched with `\1`" (BUG #2)
5. `""` means "only replace the first occurrence" (BUG #3)

Having said that, there are bugs:

BUG 1: `RS='\0'` doesn't **really** mean "read the whole file", it means "split the file at every NUL character" and so it only reads the whole file if the file doesn't contain any NULs (which a POSIX text file shouldn't). This should be `-v RS='^$'` instead to do what you want robustly.

BUG #2: `"\1"` makes no sense as the replacement string. `"\\1"` would mean "replace with whatever matched the first capture group" and so would remove the last comma from the file as you want.

BUG #3: `""` in that context will generate a warning message in newer versions of gawk since that's supposed to be a number (e.g. 1 in your case) or `"g"` for "globally"`

So after fixing the bugs your command should be:

```
gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{print gensub(/,([^,]+)$/,"\\1",1)}' tstop1
```

Comment: Great! you are faster. You are always giving great awk,sed,shell answers! I discard my answer and give you a thumb up!

Comment: oh, btw, do you probably know some resources to describe the difference between standard awk and gawk? I know there are some articles on the internet, but they are not detailed enough, e.g. I want to know the diff on each variable, function level. I didn't find a related doc at gnu site or man page. It just sometimes says "this function is gnu extension", however it seems there is no a detailed list of them.

Comment: There's this: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-55 but it's incomplete.

Comment: Thanks! asking for resources doesn't follow the SO question policy....  :(

Comment: Thanks, but the functions are not listed there. such as the `gensub()`

Comment: See `info gawk` section `POSIX/GNU` on your system or [the website](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/POSIX_002fGNU.html)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 that's a great reference, thanks for digging that up. Looks like it's incomplete (e.g. `SYMTAB` is missing and it doesn't include the available libraries or regexp escape sequences like `\<`, etc.) but it's a very good start!